# Can I use AIC to compare GLM with LM?

Tags: aic, model-comparison, qq-plot

I fit a LM model. It looks ugly, residuals are too skewed. I refit with a GLM using a skewed distribution.

But now I still need to check whether this GLM fixes the skew or not. How can I do this?

1. Use AIC to compare the two fits: if the GLM is better, it should have less AIC.
2. Use a normal qq-plot to check the residuals of the GLM. It if is a better fit, residuals should be approximately normal.
3. Perform cross-validation and see what fits the data better?
4. ???

I can of course do several things at once, but I am primarily looking for whether there's something I **shouldn't** do, or something I **definitely should** do.

Comment: You can't compare information criteria between different fitting methods, you can compare them for different models fitted by the same method. It would be helpful if you provide some more information as to what is your outcome variable and what link function are you using?

Comment: @MichaelR "You can't compare information criteria between different fitting methods" — Why not? The AIC is computed using the number of parameters and the log-likelihood, both of which are defined, and have the same meaning, for both OLS models and GLMs.